# Python (c)profile: Error importing SortKey from pstats

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to work through the docs for Python's profile(rs). I'm using Python 3.6 in Anaconda on a Win10 laptop.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

```
import cProfile
import re
cProfile.run('re.compile("foo|bar")')
```

This executes no problem, per the docs.

However,

```
import pstats
from pstats import SortKey
```

results in this error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SortKey'
```

There is a `class SortKey(str, Enum)` in this version of `pstats`:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pstats.py

However, when I look through local `pstats.py` files, I do not have that class, e.g. `~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\Lib\pstats.py` is very different than the (cPython) `pstats.py`.

I assume I am missing something obvious...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue was Python 3.6 vs Python 3.7.

3.6, no `SortKey`:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html

3.7, with `SortKey`:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/profile.html

Using an *integer* in the docs URL defaults to the latest version, e.g. 3.7, when I needed the docs for 3.6.